# Image uploading fails but doesn't error out

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I have two models, `Project` which contains information about the project and `ProjectImage` which contains all the images associated with that project (many to one relationship).  I have it set up such that a project's images can be uploaded during initial set up via an inline-formset.

When I try to create a new project with images, **it works**.  Firebug doesn't report any problems.  But my images don't upload to the media directory.  As far as I can tell they don't go anywhere.

My questions:

1). Is there anything in the below code that would prevent an image from uploading? To my mind the images should be uploading to `django_project_dir/media/images`.

2). Are there any tools that can help me debug these sorts of issues in the future?

**Folder Setup:**

```
folder/
    env/
    project_dir/
        app/
        project_dir/
            settings.py
        media/
            images/
```

**Settings.py:**

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**Models.py:**

```
class ProjectImage(TimeStamp):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

**Views.py:**

```
class CreateProject(CreateView):
    model = Project
    template_name = "manage_project.html"
    form_class = CreateProjectForm

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        project_image_form = ProjectImageFormSet()

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form=form,
                project_image_form = project_image_form,
            )
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        project_image_form = ProjectImageFormSet(self.request.POST)

        if form.is_valid() and project_image_form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form, project_image_form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form, project_image_form)

    def form_valid(self, form, project_image_form):
        self.object = form.save()
        project_image_form.instance = self.object
        project_image_form.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())

    def form_invalid(self, form, project_image_form):
        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form = form,
                project_image_form = project_image_form,
            )
        )

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('list-project')
```

**Forms.py:**

```
class CreateProjectForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['name'].label = "Project Name"
        self.fields['description'].label = "Project Description"
        self.fields['github'].label = "Github Link"
        self.fields['public'].label = "Public?"

    class Meta:
        model = Project

ProjectImageFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Project, ProjectImage)
```

Comment: Add `self.request.FILES` to the form's class instance.

Comment: Also, set ``enctype="multipart/form-data"`` in your ``<form>``

Comment: @sk1p yea its set already.

Comment: @pancakes How exactly should I go about doing that?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ColtonAllen `ProjectImageFormSet(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)`